# React Native | Flatlist & memo | renderItem is not function

Tags: reactjs, react-native, flatlist

I have a list. There are 10 elements in it. I show this with flatlist. But when 1 of the 10 elements on the list changes, it renders 10 of them again. I was going to solve this problem with memo (flatlist has to do this by itself, but anyway) but I'm getting a syntax error. Err: renderItem is not function.

```
const Item = React.memo( ({item}) => (
   <Text>{item.name}</Text>
))

const List = () => {
  return (
     <FlatList
        ..
        renderItem = {Item}
     >
)}
export default React.memo(List);
```

Answer (score 2):

**replace this**

```
renderItem = {Item}
```

**with**

```
renderItem={({ item }) => <Item item={item} />}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. There is no non-inline method. Is this the only solution?

Answer (score 0):

> But when 1 of the 10 elements on the list changes, it renders 10 of
> them again

I think you forgot to add Flatlist **extraData** prop. For more detail check [this](https://reactnative.dev/docs/flatlist#extradata).

Comment: Thank you for answering. For this example, would you write the extraData assuming that item.name has changed?

Comment: can you put your complete example, please?.

Comment: Another question that came to the same place. Here is a clearer example. You can write there. Thank you for your attention. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65034994/react-native-rerender-flatlist

Comment: when you use setstate to update data, the whole app is re-render including Flatlist.