# React Native | Rerender Flatlist

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I have a list: data. Then when I update the list, it renders all the elements again. For example, let's say there are 10 items. One of these has changed. 10 items are rendering again. But since 9 of them are the same, they should not be rendered again. How can I do?

```
const Item =({item}) => (
   <Text>{item.name}</Text>
)

const List = () => {
  const [data, setData] = useState([..]);

  return (
     <FlatList
        data={data}
        renderItem = {Item}
     >
)}
export default List;
```

Comment: `(<View key={item.key}><Text>{item.title}</Text></View>)` - Using `key` field solve this issue ? Not sure....just a thought

Comment: Thank you for answering. It does not work.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `extraData` prop of `Flatlist`

**According to docs:**

`By passing extraData={this.state} to FlatList we make sure FlatList will re-render itself when the state.selected changes. Without setting this prop, FlatList would not know it needs to re-render any items because it is also a PureComponent and the prop comparison will not show any changes.`

Or you can implement shouldComponentUpdate inside your `renderitem` component and place a check when you wanted to render your component.

Comment: Thank you for answering. For this example, would you write the extraData assuming that item.name has changed?

Comment: Then I will go with `shouldComponentUpdate`